# ssh ControlPath use ip address instead of hostame %h

Tags: ssh, openssh

Presently I am using this for controlpath

```
  ControlPath /home/user/.ssh/sockets/ssh_mux_%h_%p_%r
```

If i connect to a hostname 'redishost' it creates socket with redishost
If i connect to same host 'redishost' with its ip address it creates socket with ip address

> Is it possible to use ip for all ssh connections instead of hostname %h in controlpath
>   ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after checking openssh documentation and source I found that `openssh don't have any token for controlpath expression where ip address can be specified.`
In case if you want to use it you can use my repo which I edited source of openssh and added the token %x for ip address resolving.

Now ControlPath becomes:

```
  ControlPath /home/user/.ssh/sockets/ssh_mux_%x_%p_%r
```

ControlPath supported tokens:

```
        "l", thishost,
        "n", host_arg,              "n", host_arg,
        "p", portstr,               "p", portstr,
        "x", hostip,
        "r", options.user,              "r", options.user,
        "u", pw->pw_name,               "u", pw->pw_name,
        "i", uidstr,                "i", uidstr,
        "h", host,
```

https://github.com/akhilin/openssh-portable/commit/a2d95e090b73f36590e8c189685ce8cea810f49a

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem possible, as the only token you can use to refer to the remote host is %h. See https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#TOKENS.

Can you reveal a bit more about the motivation to use the IP address instead of the hostname? Then maybe we can find an alternate solution to that problem.

Comment: I am using ansible.it connects to hosts using ip addresses.But generally I use hostnames for ssh connections.Because of this its creating two different sockets for same host.so I can't make use of ControlPath here.But if I use %ip instead of %h in controlpath , this resolves the problem.

Comment: It it possible use this ```https://github.com/akhilin/openssh-portable/blob/fd0fa130ecf06d7d092932adcd5d77f1549bfc8d/session.c#L2620``` and assign a new token for resolved ip address.